# JavaScript runtime error "irrationalPath" in Dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo, arcgis, httpcontext, arcgis-js-api

I'm using the dojo javascript file at http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/?v=3.3 to display a map on an ASP.NET page.

The map has suddenly stopped displaying and i'm running into a javascript error that i have posted [Getting JavaScript runtime error: irrationalPath, what does it mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34806232/getting-javascript-runtime-error-irrationalpath-what-does-it-mean)

To debug this issue, i made a local uncompressed copy of the javascript file at http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/?v=3.3 and referenced that in my application.

When this dojo javaScript is being called, i'm getting the below error which in the end stops the map from displaying

> JavaScript runtime error: irrationalPath

During debugging, i found that the function that is throwing the path is below

```
_9b = function (mid, _9c, _9d, _9e, _9f, _a0, _a1, _a2) {
        var pid, _a3, _a4, _a5, _a6, url, _a7, _a8, _a9;
        _a9 = mid;
        _a8 = /^\./.test(mid);
        if (/(^\/)|(\:)|(\.js$)/.test(mid) || (_a8 && !_9c)) {
            return _81(0, mid, 0, mid);
        } else {
            mid = _95(_a8 ? (_9c.mid + "/../" + mid) : mid);
            if (/^\./.test(mid)) {
                debugger;
                throw _f("irrationalPath", mid);
            }
            if (_9c) {
                _a6 = _93(_9c.mid, _a0);
            }
            _a6 = _a6 || _a0.star;
            _a6 = _a6 && _93(mid, _a6[1]);
            if (_a6) {
                mid = _a6[1] + mid.substring(_a6[3]);
            }
            _70 = mid.match(/^([^\/]+)(\/(.+))?$/);
            pid = _70 ? _70[1] : "";
            if ((_a3 = _9d[pid])) {
                mid = pid + "/" + (_a4 = (_70[3] || _a3.main));
            } else {
                pid = "";
            }
            var _aa = 0,
                _ab = 0;
            _9(_4c, function (_ac) {
                var _ad = mid.match(_ac[0]);
                if (_ad && _ad.length > _aa) {
                    _ab = _6(_ac[1]) ? mid.replace(_ac[0], _ac[1]) : _ac[1];
                }
            });
            if (_ab) {
                return _9b(_ab, 0, _9d, _9e, _9f, _a0, _a1, _a2);
            }
            _a7 = _9e[mid];
            if (_a7) {
                return _a2 ? _81(_a7.pid, _a7.mid, _a7.pack, _a7.url) : _9e[mid];
            }
        }
        _a6 = _93(mid, _a1);
        if (_a6) {
            url = _a6[1] + mid.substring(_a6[3]);
        } else {
            if (pid) {
                url = _a3.location + "/" + _a4;
            } else {
                if (has("config-tlmSiblingOfDojo")) {
                    url = "../" + mid;
                } else {
                    url = mid;
                }
            }
        }
        if (!(/(^\/)|(\:)/.test(url))) {
            url = _9f + url;
        }
        url += ".js";
        return _81(pid, mid, _a3, _95(url));
    }
```

When i put a breakpoint at the line before the error is thrown, the value of variable "**mid**" is coming as "**../css/jsapi.css/*.*/x**" and that path does not exist in my application, does it have to?

Also what does the line `if (/(^\/)|(\:)|(\.js$)/.test(mid) || (_a8 && !_9c))` actually do? it is not returning true for all the time i have tested.

What is also this `if (/^\./.test(mid))` doing?

This is my very first time to touch anything to do with dojo, so apologies if i'm not clear but i can always clarify.

**UPDATE:**
The error is thrown at the below line of code in a javascript function

```
document.getElementById(menu_number).src = "<%=HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath%>/UI/Common/Images/down-arrow.gif";
```

Comment: I'm assuming your asp variable substitution didn't get resolved? `<%=HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath%>` of course Dojo isn't going to know what this means. What is the actual line of Javascript that's sent to the browser?

Comment: it's also unlikely that the error is being caused by the minified dojo library. While certainly possible that there's a bug in the library it would be more helpful to post your own code.

Comment: `irrationalPath` means the loader was unable to ultimately resolve a relative module ID to an absolute one. This is usually caused by an incorrect `require` dependency in your own code, so it would help to see that.  I also see no direct references to `jsapi.css` in Esri's layer, so I suspect there's something else at play.

Comment: The following error is also coming up in chrome developer tools:--"XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://lkm-gis-po.pro.xm.org/arcgis/rest/info?f=json. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://pbt-imt-01.sb.pro.xm.org' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500."

Comment: You are apparently trying to access a cross-domain resource via XHR, when [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) is not enabled for that resource. Seems completely unrelated to your original question though...